# If I use headers only while using Boost, will that link it statically, or is that not linking at all?

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking

I'm developing a small ATL DLL file in Windows/Visual Studio IDE, and I'm relatively new to C++/Boost. I've added the Boost library directory under the *Linker options*, and added the Boost root directory as an additional include directory. In my code I'm adding it like:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
```

Will this be statically linked, dynamically linked, or not linked at all?

Comment: Boost.StringAlgo is header-only; header-only means no linking involved.

Comment: And the effects are the same that statically-linking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this be statically linked, dynamically linked, or not linked at all?

The answer is "It depends".

Boost is big. To steal a line from Douglas Adams, Boost "is big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly big it is."

Some parts of Boost are implemented purely as templates: There are no calls to functions that were previously compiled and stored in some library. Use just these parts of Boost and there is no need for the Boost library.

Other parts of Boost do call functions that were previously compiled and stored in some library. These will need to be linked in. Whether that is done dynamically or statically depends on (a) whether you (or some sysadmin) built the Boost library as a dynamic vs. static library, and (b) how you (or your makefile) tells the linker to treat the Boost library.

Answer (score 2):

Including **any** headers will embed that code in your source files for compilation.

So the code will be linked, as all your symbols will be, but **it's not separately linked**.

Comment: Wasn't there some special "stuff" in visual studio like `#pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib")` that could be used to specify files to link from within headers?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, and boost uses that for libraries that aren't header-only. But most boost libraries are header-only.

Comment: @bames53: So the best answer to the OP question would depend on the files he actually uses...?

Comment: So it would seem.  I'm seeing that if I use libraries like boost.Threads, that I'd have to link them.  For the moment, it appears as though as long as I use the header only libraries, I should be good.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yes.  **Most** don't need linking, but a few do.  My answer is dependant on my interpretation of OP "using headers only"